# Angular 2: *ngFor in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

The following scenario would be pretty easy in javascript but I got some problems getting it worked in Angular.

I got an Array like:

```
array a = ( "id" = 0, name = random(), column = 1, 2 or 3, blockrow= 1, 2 or 3)
```

With ngFor I try to create now a grid there all elements out of a get separated in colums and blocks in this column. So my current code (works but nasty).

```html
<div *ngFor="let a of a">
  <template [ngIf]="a.column=='1'">
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
      <template [ngIf]="b.blockrow=='1'">
        Block 1 in column 1{{b.name}}
      </template>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
      <template [ngIf]="b.blockrow=='2'">
        Block 2 in column 1{{b.name}}
      </template>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
      <template [ngIf]="b.blockrow=='3'">
        Block 3 in column 1{{b.name}}
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Something like this do I run for every column. Which means I loop trough the same array for 12 times. Is there any way to do it more beautifull ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your component, use JavaScript to build an array of arrays with the elements of **a** at the right coordinates, then use *ngFor inside *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <div *ngFor="let col of row">
    Block {{col.blockrow}} in column {{col.column}} {{col.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

A third *ngFor might be needed if several blocks have the same coordinates.

Comment: So I can work with multidimensionals Arrays this way. Perfect thank you this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax should be `*ngIf` instead of  `[ngIf]`

```
<div *ngFor="let a of a">
  <template *ngIf="a.column=='1'">
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
      <template *ngIf="b.blockrow=='1'">
        Block 1 in column 1{{b.name}}
      </template>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
      <template *ngIf="b.blockrow=='2'">
        Block 2 in column 1{{b.name}}
      </template>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
      <template *ngIf="b.blockrow=='3'">
        Block 3 in column 1{{b.name}}
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Changed it top, the editor uses angular 1, but this is not my problem. Just want to know if there is a way to run the loop not so often.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: In my example I loop trough the same array 4 times. To make it completly working I need this 3 times, which means 12 times looping trough the same array. In my eyes this is very inefficient. In plain JS I could do the same with going only once trough the array. So my question is, is there a way to do this block of code better ? Something like if b.blockrow == 1 -> add to div1, if b.blockrow == 2 add to div 2.

Comment: Btw. tried your change in my angular app with *ngIf it does not work. The documentation also says [ngIf] for template.

Comment: what is the exact problem.

Comment: There is no problem, It just slowdown my project. So I would like to know if there is a way to handle it with less loops.

Comment: @Doomenik take a look at [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore ty this one gets closer to what I want but it still prints anyway a element in my DOM. This would let my DOM explode by unfilled elements. Anyway its a good direction to look for me so thank you. Eventually I can combine it with template.